# Flask App Accessible on Localhost but Not on Private IP Address

Tags: python, windows, flask, networking, firewall

I'm making a Flask app and trying to make it accessible on my local network to test it on my phone. I run the app with the following settings to make it externally visible on my local network:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, threaded=False)
```

When I do this the console outputs what you would expect:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://[localhost]:5000
 * Running on http://[private_IP]:5000
```

However, the app is only accessible via localhost and not via the private IP, even on the same machine. Here's what I have checked and tried so far:

- The firewall ([simplewall](https://www.henrypp.org/product/simplewall)) allows connections on port 5000
- I tried deactivating simplewall too, and deactivating Windows Defender Firewall as well, no luck
- The IP address is correct, as listed with ipconfig
- No other service is using port 5000
- I attempted to connect to the app using both my home WiFi and my phone's mobile hotspot, encountering the same issue in both scenarios to rule out router-specific problems
- My hosts file doesn't seem to be causing any issues

In case this is relevant, I am running the Flask app through VS Code on Windows 11.

Comment: Could it be that u have Network Isolation in your WLAN Router activ? Because u try connecting with your Phone. Did u test it with other Computer or Laptop on same LAN?

Comment: To clarify, I tried connecting to http://[local_IP]:5000 from both my Windows PC (from which the flask is served) and from my phone connected to the same Wifi network. And I tried that on both my home Wifi network, and on my mobile hotspot, in case that was an issue with my commercial router. None of this worked.

Comment: I would test with a second machine or so, also you could install a portscanner and a ping tool on your phone, first check if u can ping your windows pc where flask app runs, then check if port is open and not blocked. Its 99.9% a network issue and not flask issue because its works local.